# Nginx + php-fpm return 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: php, nginx

I read all related questions and my config options the same as there

I use

```
MacOS Monteray
Nginx version: nginx/1.21.4
PHP 7.2.34
```

I checked all config params

phpinfo returns

```
max_execution_time: 300
```

nginx -T

```
fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=300";
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
```

php-fpm -tt

```
request_terminate_timeout = 300s
```

nginx -t

```
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I reloaded php-fpm and nginx several times and even restarted my laptop but still have 60s timeout (((

I don't know what can I check else.

Comment: Check nginx log

Comment: Checked, no errors, no notices, nothing (
(nginx and fpm logs are enabled)

Comment: Does 504 occur with a simple PHP script like? `<?php echo "1"; ?>`?

Comment: Sure. I check the script before to test. I even have two the first one with echo and the second with the sleep function.